# Unpacking nested data from Rapid API

Tags: python, json, visual-studio-code, python-requests, rapidapi

pretty new to both stack overflow and python so my apologies if the formatting is wrong. Not sure if necessary but I am using VS Code.

I am pulling data from a covid-19 rapid api and it outputs the data (json) but doesn't give me the data I actually need:

This is the code to pull it:

```
import requests  

url = "https://covid-19-data.p.rapidapi.com/report/country/code"  

querystring = {"date":"2020-04-01","code":"it"}  
headers = { 'x-rapidapi-host': "covid-19-data.p.rapidapi.com", 'x-rapidapi-key': "SIGN-UP-FOR-KEY" }  

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring) print(response.text)
```

Once I get that, it outputs:

```
[{"country":"USA","provinces":[{"province":"USA"}],"latitude":37.09024,"longitude":-95.712891,"date":"2022-01-24"}]
```

However, on the rapid api website, it shows under 'Example Responses' that the data I need (deaths, recovered, active, etc.) is nested under the  [{"province":"USA"}]  section:

```
[1 item
    0:{5 items
         "country":"Italy"
                 "provinces":[1 item
                    0:{5 items
                           "province":"Italy"
                           "confirmed":110574
                           "recovered":16847
                           "deaths":13155
                           "active":80572
                        }
                     ]
             "latitude":41.87194
             "longitude":12.56738
             "date":"2020-04-01"
        }
    ]
```

I want to pull the data from that nested dictionary but I am not sure how.
This is my attempt which hasn't worked but just wanted to show the data:

```
import requests
import json

def get_covid_data_19(country_code, date):
    '''
    This function gets COVID 19 data via rapid API. This takes two parameters: 
    Country Name (string) and Date (YYYY-MM-DD)

    '''
    c = country_code
    d = date
    # Endpoint that we are going to be hitting:
    url = "https://covid-19-data.p.rapidapi.com/report/country/code"

    querystring = {"code" : c, "date" : d}

    headers = {
        'x-rapidapi-host': "covid-19-data.p.rapidapi.com",
        'x-rapidapi-key': "insertkeyhere"
        }

    response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
    json_data = response.json()
    
    data = []
    for response in json_data:
        data.append ({
            'confirmed' : response.get('confirmed'),
            'recovered' : response.get('recovered'),
            'deaths' : response.get('deaths'),
            'active' : response.get('active'),
            'date' : response.get('date'),
        })

    print(data)
```

I also attemped to retrieve the data as xml format and could not figure out how to expand the array either.
Any advice would be awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

These are all the endpoints of the API.

[image]

You are using the "Country/Code" endpoint, which will return the Covid stats in the provinces array. You need to traverse the array to get the stats of each province in the country. I have confirmed that it shows stats for USA. [Try looking at this official RapidAPI guide](https://rapidapi.com/guides/build-covid-app) on creating an app with this API, it might help.